# Proof that the finite product of nonempty sets is nonempty without axiom of choice from ZF

Tags: reference-request, set-theory, axiom-of-choice, axioms

How do you prove that for $X_{i} \neq \emptyset$, $i \in \{1,...,n\}$ that $\prod_{i=1}^{n} X_{i} \neq \emptyset$ only using the ZF axioms but not the Axiom of Choice? I would like to see a rigorous proof. It would be nice if someone could direct me to a book containing such a proof.

EDIT: I am looking for literature where this is proved STRICTLY from the ZF axioms.

Comment: This can be done by induction on $n$.

Comment: This can be done by searching for the several occasions where this question has been asked before on the site.

Comment: @AsafKaragila The OP asked in his question for a book where this is proved, and he apparently wants the proof to be quite formalized. I don't see an answer to that question in the question this is supposed to be a duplicate of.

Comment: @user208259: You're right.

Answer (score 4):

The proof is simple enough that you don't need a book. You just prove it by induction. The base case (one set) is trivial, and the inductive case is not much harder, using the fact that $$\prod_{i = 1}^{n+1} X_i \cong \left (\prod_{i=1}^n X_i\right ) \times X_{n+1}.$$

Comment: It is simple because it is not rigorous, meaning that it's not a direct formal derivation only using the axioms, which is what I'm looking for, more precisely, a book containing such a derivation.

Comment: @user159517: I looked through several books but found nothing. This is the sort of thing that is left as a remark "Prove by induction" or an exercise to the reader. Do you "accept" a proof using the induction theorem (on natural numbers) as a valid proof? Because based on the induction theorem it **is** an easy proof, and formal proofs of induction (as a specific principle, or an application of transfinite induction limited to $\omega$) is easier to find references to.

Comment: Induction in ZF is particularly easy: $\omega$ is defined as the intersection of all sets of ordinals that contain $0$ and are closed under successor. So we just have the prove that the set of ordinals $\alpha$ that are zero or for which products of length $\alpha$ are nonemmpty, is closed under successor.

Comment: @AsafKaragila thank you for your efforts. I wanted to use this fact in a proof that Tychonoff's theorem implies the Axiom of Choice. Unfortunately, I was unable to find any reference containing a strictly formalized proof, and in my eyes, any other kind of reference would miss the point. But if you could direct me to a book that is written in this highly formalized style and contains this question as an exercise I think that would suffice, I might have to go through all of it and do the proof myself, but I am sure it would help.

Comment: @user159517: Halbeisen's book is very formal; as is Kunen's book (at least the old edition). I'd start with the latter.